# find files where Change > Birth

Tags: linux, unix-timestamp

Is it possible to find files where Change > Birth?

Stat somefile shows this for a modifed file

```
Access: 2022-02-24 17:07:45.562037727 +0000
Modify: 2022-02-24 17:07:26.682343514 +0000
Change: 2022-02-24 17:07:26.682343514 +0000
 Birth: 2022-02-24 16:35:56.737147848 +0000
```

and this for a non-modifed one (a copied file)

```
Access: 2022-02-23 18:27:00.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2022-02-23 18:27:00.000000000 +0000
Change: 2022-02-24 15:57:29.334302184 +0000
 Birth: 2022-02-24 15:57:29.334302184 +0000
```

The modification time is the timestamp of the orginal file, a little less than the  time it was copied into a docker image.

I'd like to `find` only the modified files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little script in **bash**,  to find if `change "path1" > birth "path2"`.

The following sketch for a script assumes that `change, birth` have values.

```
change=$(stat "<path1>" | awk '/Change/ {$1=""; print}')
birth=$(stat "<path2>" | awk '/Birth/ {$1=""; print}')

if [ $change -ge $birth ];
then
    echo "greater"
fi
```

Comment: Counting characters with `grep | cut` is a bit fragile.  It would be better to do something like `stat "$path1" | awk '/Change/ {$1=""; print}'`

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell. Can you point me to **docs** about the fragility of `grep | cut`?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with `grep | cut`, but counting the characters explicitly is prone to error.  (eg, the `cut -c6-` is probably wrong, since that will pick up the `:` or the `h` depending on the leading whitespace. In either case, it grabs characters that you don't want.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you create six files, wait a sec then touch 3 of them again to update their `mtime`:

```
$ touch file{1..6}; sleep 1; touch file{2..4}
```

You can find the files that have been modified with `ruby`:

```
ruby -e '
    Dir.glob("file*").each{|fn|
        st=File.stat(fn)
        puts "\"#{fn}\" satisfies the condition" if st.mtime>st.birthtime
    }
'
```

Or with Bash:

```
# The `stat` command tends to be SUPER platform specific
# This is BSD and likely only works on BSD / Mac OS
# Just modify that `stat` command to print mtime and btime for your platform
for fn in file*; do
    mtime=$(stat -f "%m" "$fn")
    btime=$(stat -f "%B" "$fn")
    (( mtime>btime )) && echo "\"${fn}\" satisfies the condition"
done
```

Either prints:

```
"file2" satisfies the condition
"file3" satisfies the condition
"file4" satisfies the condition
```